# Display all categories in WP, with the selected in bold

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all the categories existing in my Wordpress in the bottom of the content, with the selected for the current post in bold, as follows.
For example, for an existing post I selected category2 of 3 existing.

category1 **category2** category3

How can I do this?

My code (now only display the selected category):

```
<div class="entry-meta">
<span class="term-links">
<?php foreach ( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category') as $term ) : 
?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id ) ) 
?>"><span class="<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?>
</span></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</span>

<style>
.term-links .category2 {
display: inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
</style>
```

Comment: please share your code also. so we can give the answer.

Comment: @ShitalMarakana you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list of all category

add below code in your template

```
<style type="text/css">
        .single-product div.product .product_meta .product_cat ul li{ list-style-type:circle;}
        .single-product div.product .product_meta .product_cat ul li.current-cat{list-style-type:circle;}
        .single-product div.product .product_meta .product_cat ul li.current-cat a{display: inline-block;font-weight:bold;}
        </style>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        $product_cat_id_array = array();
        foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
            $product_cat_id_array[]  = $term->term_id;
        }
        $product_cat_id_string = implode(",",$product_cat_id_array);

        $args = array(
            'child_of'            => 0,
            'current_category'    => $product_cat_id_string,
            'depth'               => 0,
            'echo'                => 1,
            'exclude'             => '',
            'exclude_tree'        => '',
            'feed'                => '',
            'feed_image'          => '',
            'feed_type'           => '',
            'hide_empty'          => 0,
            'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
            'hierarchical'        => true,
            'order'               => 'ASC',
            'orderby'             => 'name',
            'separator'           => '',
            'show_count'          => 0,
            'show_option_all'     => '',
            'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
            'style'               => 'list',
            'taxonomy'            => 'product_cat',
            'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
            'use_desc_for_title'  => 0,
        );
        wp_list_categories($args);
     ?>
```

Comment: It only displays the current category, @ShitalMarakana

Comment: are you use code in single post? detail page right.

Comment: What I exactly did was: Create a custom taxonomy for WooCommerce product ('category', in the example). I want to display all available 'categories' with the currently assigned to the product in bold, after the short description. With the provided code i wrote it only shows the assigned to the product, but i need to display all of them. @shitalmarakana

Comment: but you are assigned 3 category of one product. how can check category2 only? are you listing all category? right then display only 3 category in bold?

Comment: I assigned only 1 category to the product, but i want to display all the available categories, with the assigned displayed in bold. @shitalmarakana.

Comment: The exact functonality is this: The products are seeds. Some of them are planted in spring, other in other seasons. Each season is a category, and every product (seed) has a category, corresponding to the season in which it must be planted. I want to display all seasons, with the currently assigned (season of planting) in bold @shitalmarakana Oh, it could be more than one category assigned, of course.